# How to define a list using a user-input string as its name (in python)?

Tags: python, list

I want to define lists at running-time using strings input by the user as their names. Example:

```
User input        >> "Cars"
python should do  >> cars[]
so later i can do >> cars.append("BMW")
```

Thanks.

Comment: You shouldn't use dynamic variable names like this.

Comment: globals()[user_input] = []
wher user input is your user input, buuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuut be careful

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Why not?

Comment: @user190081 because it is considered a bad practice. How will you refer to these variables in code? You'll end up hackily using the `globals()` dict, but why? Just use your own `dict` object.

Comment: In this situation, the proper solution is almost always to use a dict, or perhaps a list. For more info on this topic, please see [Why you don't want to dynamically create variables](http://stupidpythonideas.blogspot.com/2013/05/why-you-dont-want-to-dynamically-create.html).